# nginx server failure after adding server block to config file

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I am using nginx version 1.4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. I need to redirect the URI to `http://my-ip/website/index.html` when a user types `http://my-ip` . I made changes to the config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, as follows.

```
server {
    server_name my-ip;
    location = / {
        rewrite ^ http://my-ip/website/ redirect;
    }
}
```

I put the above inside the "http" block.
After this, when I do `sudo service nginx restart`, it shows Fail. But, when I see in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, no message is logged. So, I am unable to find the reason for starting failure. `nginx -t` shows as configuration is fine. If, I remove the server block, and then do `service nginx restart`, it works fine. I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you better use a 302 redirect, if you want google to keep / as your landing page

Answer (score 0):

You can   use the `return` instead of `rewrite`. look  bellow:

```
 location = / {
        return 301 http://my-ip/website/index.htlm;
    }
```